# Rails 5.1, code improvement, search query (scope), by date and filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, filter, scope, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a rails app and I have a search query using scope. The code is working but I'm pretty sure it's not written the best way and I would like to improve it to be more reliable in the futur if I want to add some stuff for example.

This is my view:

```
<%= form_tag spendings_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= date_field_tag "search[date_from]", @search.date_from, class: 'form-control col-2 d-inline-block' %>
  <%= date_field_tag "search[date_to]", @search.date_to, class: 'form-control col-2 d-inline-block' %>
  <%= select_tag "search[user_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, :id, :firstname, params[:user_id]), include_blank: "All Users", class: 'form-control col-2 d-inline-block' %>
  <%= select_tag "search[currency_id]", options_from_collection_for_select(Currency.all, :id, :name, params[:currency_id]), include_blank: "All Currencies", class: 'form-control col-2 d-inline-block' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-secondary d-inline-block" %> <%= link_to "Reset", spendings_path, class: "btn btn-secondary d-inline-block" %>
<% end %>
```

Here already, I'm refreshing the page to "Reset" the filters. Is it a good option ?
My controller :

```
@search = SpendingSearch.new(params[:search])
```

My helper :

```
@search.scope.order('date DESC').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

And finally my model which is only created for this search purpose :

```
class SpendingSearch
  attr_reader :date_from, :date_to, :user_id, :currency_id  

  def initialize(params)
    params ||= {}
    @date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from], 1.month.ago.to_date.to_s)
    @date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.tomorrow.to_s)
    @user_id = params[:user_id]
    @currency_id = params[:currency_id]
  end

  def scope
    if @user_id.present? && @currency_id.present?
      Spending.where("date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND user_id = ? AND currency_id = ?", @date_from, @date_to, @user_id, @currency_id)
    elsif @user_id.present?
      Spending.where("date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND user_id = ?", @date_from, @date_to, @user_id)
    elsif @currency_id.present?
      Spending.where("date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND currency_id = ?", @date_from, @date_to, @currency_id)
    else
      Spending.where("date BETWEEN ? AND ?", @date_from, @date_to)
    end
  end

  private

  def parsed_date(date_string, default)
    Date.parse(date_string)
  rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    default
  end        
end
```

As you can see the worst is here... This scope is a little bit ridiculous.

Basically I'm looking for `dates`, `user_id` and `currency_id`. If the `currency_id` and the `user_id` are left blank (as I include blank in the view) I want the result to show all the `user_id` and the `currency_id`.

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this, I just don't know which one it could be.

Again, I know it's the point to give me the code, I'm just looking to improve here, so anything like, maybe you should check that out or here is a link that could help would be very nice.

Maybe I should change everything and I just don't know, I'm not a rails expert, any tips, tricks or hint is very appreciate.

Thank you very much.

Comment: OK, That's mean the current code is working properly for search? Right?

Comment: Currently it's working perfectly yes. It's just bad writting I would say :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below `scope` method:

```
def scope
  s_scope = Spending.where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?', @date_from, @date_to)
  s_scope = s_scope.where(user_id: @user_id) if @user_id.present?
  s_scope = s_scope.where(currency_id: @currency_id) if @currency_id.present?

  s_scope
end
```

Also, I believe that you can change:

```
@date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from], 1.month.ago.to_date.to_s)
@date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.tomorrow.to_s)
```

to

```
@date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from], 1.month.ago.to_date)
@date_to = parsed_date(params[:date_to], Date.tomorrow)
```

Comment: I tried the code, `spending_scope` is not defined. I tried by changing it with `Spending.where` but it looks like that if I search by date, user and currency it shows me everything

Comment: Ok no... my bad, I changed it like so : `s_scope.where(user_id: @user_id) if @user_id.present?`. Looks like it works, I will try a little bit more. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Sorry, I have changed spending_scope to s_scope for shorten the statements but forgot to replace all. I have fixed the mistake.

Comment: That's it, yes. Thanks you very much. It's way better and I learned something new. Thanks @Tai !